# Feed-through termination

Tags: wiring, termination

I have a very basic question about rf-electronics: I tried to understand how feed-through terminators work, but I could not find a wiring diagram online.

Intuitively it would make sense to me if such a feed-through terminator is equivalent to a t-piece with a termination at one end of it, e.g. for a 50 Ohm feed-through terminator I would expect to have a 50 Ohm termination at one output of the t-piece and the output-signal at the other end of the t-piece.

Is this a legitimate way of understanding this?

Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a feed through terminator

- courtesy of [EEVblog](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/testgear/50-ohm-feed-through-terminator/)

[image]
[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwhm3k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is the schematics, you can use N parallel resistors of value N x 50 Ohm.

Comment: Okay, but how would the wiring diagram look like?

Comment: The schematic in this answer is the "wiring diagram". If you wish to use other resistance values (which are multiples of 50 ohms in value) they would be in parallel per this diagram. For example the two 100 ohm resistors in the diagram could be replaced with 3 x 150 ohm resistors in parallel connected  between the "in-out" rail and ground.

Comment: Ok okay, now I understand!! And since the two resistors are in parallel, we end up with the 50 Ohm total resistance. Thank you very much!! Would there be an advantage of using 3 x 150 Ohm compared to 2 x 100 Ohm, or is it just an alternative to achieve exactly the same result?